# Is there a way to write less code when defining vars in PHP constructor?

Tags: php

I have this code, but it is so repetitive, because all the vars are an array:

```
    class User {
        public function __construct(
            private $groupData = array(),
            private $nameData = array(),
            private $nameSData = array(),
            private $OData = array(),
            private $uwoData = array(),
            private $lReq = array(),
            private $lReqB = array(),
            private $lReqC = array(),
            private $nameMData = array(),
            private $typeData = array(),
            private $equipamiento = array(),
            private $equip = array(),
            private $brandData = array(),
            private $provData = array(),
            private $typeData2 = array(),
            private $lSol = array(),
            private $lSolP = array(),
            private $officS = array(),
            private $officeG = array(),
            private $lReqFO = array(),
            private $reporta_fallo = array(),
            private $rFallo = array(),
            private $lFalloFO = array(),
            private $sTypeData = array(),
            private $equipFID = array(),
            private $lReqPFO = array(),
            private $lFalloPFO = array(),
            private $lEquipFO = array(),
            private $lSolSP = array(),
            private $lSolS = array(),
            private $lSolFID = array(),
            private $lReqCID = array(),
            private $OSData = array(),
            private $equipFAO = array(),
            private $officeFS = array(),
            private $lReqSA = array(),
            private $lReqA = array(),
            private $lTypeFID = array(),
            private $lReqCA = array(),
            private $lTypeS = array(),
            private $depData = array(),
            private $lNext = array(),
            private $lReqBA = array()
        ) {}
    }
```

Is there a way I can reduce the amount of code written? Because I don't want to always say that a var is equal to an array if every other already is.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what your intentions with your `User` class are, or what all the properties are supposed to represent, from the looks of it your `User` class is way too bloated.

However, consider grouping related properties into their own objects, like so:

```php
class ProfileData
{
  private string $image;
  private int $backgroupColor;
  
  public function __construct(string $image, int $backgroupColor) {
    $this->image = $image;
    $this->backgroupColor = $backgroupColor;
  }
}

class ContactData
{
  private array $emailAddresses;
  private array $phoneNumbers;
  
  public function __construct(array $emailAddresses = [], array $phoneNumbers = []) {
    $this->emailAddresses = $emailAddresses;
    $this->phoneNumbers = $phoneNumbers;
  }
}

class OtherData
{
  // ...etc.
}
```

...and then passing those to your `User` constructor:

```php
class User 
{
  private ProfileData $profileData;
  private ?ContactData $otherData;
  private ?OtherData $contactData;
  
  public function __construct(
    ProfileData $profileData, 
    ContactData $contactData = null, 
    OtherData $otherData = null
  ) {
    $this->profileData = $profileData;
    $this->contactData = $contactData;
    $this->otherData = $otherData;
  }
  
  public function getProfileData() : ProfileData {
    return $this->profileData;
  }
  
  // ...etc.
}
```

Then, if your `User` still consumes too many constructor arguments, consider creating a `UserBuilder` class, whose constructor only takes the required `User` constructor arguments and allows you to set other optional arguments with setter methods (`set...()`):

```php
class UserBuilder
{
  private ProfileData $profileData;
  private ?ContactData $contactData;
  private ?OtherData $otherData;
  
  public function __construct(ProfileData $profileData) {
    $this->profileData = $profileData;
  }
  
  public function setContactData(?ContactData $contactData) : UserBuilder {
    $this->contactData = $contactData;
    
    // return $this to allow method chaining
    return $this;
  }
  
  public function setOtherData(?OtherData $otherData) : UserBuilder {
    $this->otherData = $otherData;
    
    // return $this to allow method chaining
    return $this;
  }
  
  public function build() : User {
    // build and return User object
    return new User(
      $this->profileData,
      $this->contactData,
      $this->otherData
    );
  }
}

// usage example
$builder = new UserBuilder(ProfileData('path/to/image', 0xCCCCC));

$user = $builder->setContactData(new ContactData(['info@example.com']))
                ->setOtherData(new OtherData())
                ->build();
```

For convenience you can add a static builder constructor function in your `User` class:

```php
class User 
{
  public static function builder(ProfileData $profileData) : UserBuilder {
    return new UserBuilder($profileData);
  }
}

// usage example
$user = User::builder(ProfileData('path/to/image', 0xCCCCC))
                ->setContactData(new ContactData(['info@example.com']))
                ->setOtherData(new OtherData())
                ->build();
```

Hopefully this has given you some ideas to work with.

Still though, I think you may need to reconsider your design decisions, as it really looks as though your `User` is responsible for way too much.